# How do I import a file from a folder and its contents in Python 3

Tags: python, import, module, directory, python-3.6

I am writing a program in Python 3.6 and I need to import a module and its contents. The module happens to be inside a folder that I created to keep my files organised. The folder is inside site-packages. I'd imagine it'd be something like this in one line:

```
    from folder import module import *
```

It does not work like this:

```
    from folder import module
    from module import *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from folder.module import *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from my_folder.module import *
```

Note that you'll need a `__init__.py` file inside `my_folder`

Comment: Actually, there is no need for an __init__.py file. All I needed to do is what the accepted (^^^) answer told me (answer by anonymoose) but thanks anyway